# R loop through list of list while changing values in lists

Tags: r

I have a questionnaire with many different scales, each comprising a number of questions.

```
df.scale1 = df[, list(s1_Q1, s1_Q2, s1_Q3, s1_Q4)]
df.scale2 = df[, list(s2_Q1, s2_Q2, s2_Q3, s2_Q4)]
...
df.scale20 = df[, list(s2_Q1, s2_Q2, s2_Q3, s2_Q4)]
```

Next, I would like to do the following three steps per scale:

1. Remove all rows that **only** contain NA values per scale.
2. Set all NA values left to 0 (rows that contain partly NA values are purposefully not deleted in step 1)
3. create data.matrix out of each scale
4. Get Cronbach's alpha of each scale

I can do this for a single scale:

```
# Step 1 - remove rows only containing NA values
df.scale_1 = df.scale1[rowSums(is.na(df.scale1)) != ncol(df.scale1), ]

# Step 2 - transform all NA values left to 0
dt.scale_1 [is.na(dt.scale_1 )] <- 0

# Step 3 - Transform into data.matrix
dt.scale_1 = data.matrix(dt.scale_1 )

# Step 4 - calculate Chronbach's alpha (with library umx)
reliability(cov(dt.scale_1 ))
```

However, I would like to loop through these 4 steps for each of the 20 scales. I tried the following for step 1 which did not work:

```
all_scales = list(df.scale1, df.scale2, ..., df.scale20)

for (i in all_scales ){
    i = i[rowSums(is.na(i)) != ncol(i), ]
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get all the objects into a `list` with `mget`, loop over the `list` with `lapply` apply the functions as in the OP's post and return the output of `reliability`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\.scale\\d+$')), function(dat) {
        tmp <- dat[rowSums(is.na(dat)) != ncol(dat),]
        tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
        tmp <- data.matrix(tmp)
        reliability(cov(tmp))

   })
```

---

Using a `for` loop

```
lst2 <- vector('list', length(all_scales))
for(i in seq_along(all_scales)) {
     tmp <- all_scales[[i]]
     tmp <- tmp[rowSums(is.na(tmp)) != ncol(tmp),]
     tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
     tmp <- data.matrix(tmp)
     lst2[[i]] <- reliability(cov(tmp))
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but receiving the following error message: Error: 'x' must be an array with at least two dimensions. 
Does this mean that the objects are no data.table objects? And if so, how could I transform it to data.table objects?

Comment: no error message now but lst is List of 0. 

Initially, I read the data from a csv:
```import_csv = read.csv('C:\\data.csv', sep = ';', fileEncoding = "UTF-8", na.strings=c(""))```
```df <- data.table(import_csv)```

Comment: Yes, they are in the global environment

Comment: Yes, it gives the following output:
```$`df.scale1`
$df.scale2
$df.scale3```
With the backticks in df.scale1 only

Comment: Again returning the initial error message (```x' must be an array with at least two dimensions```) and print is not possible.

class(df.scale1) returns ```"data.table" "data.frame"``` 

Thanks so much for the quick help @akrun

Comment: @Schoguan yes, it is because of the is.na(.SD), sorry forgot to replace that line earlier when I changedd the other lines of code considering it as data.table.  Now, it should work